# makefile problems (gnuplot)

Tags: makefile, gnuplot

I'm trying to produce some graphs using GNUplot with a makefile. I would like for every *.plt file in the directory to be run through GNUplot, however I can't see to get it to work.
Here's my makefile so far:

```
all: %.tex
%.tex: %.plt
<tab> gnuplot < $<
```

The recipe is working fine if I specify a .plt file individually but I want it to pick up my new plots as I produce them.

EDIT:
I think I've got it working now:

```
# plots all files in the folder with .plt extensions
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.plt)
TARGETS = $(SOURCES:.plt=.tex)

all: $(TARGETS)

%.tex: %.plt
    gnuplot < $<
```

Can someone confirm whether my reasoning (as follows) is correct?
Previously I hadn't specified any files for `all` (I'm a little confused by %). Now assigning the variable `SOURCES` by picking up any .plt files using the wildcard (why doesn't it work when using .plt instead of *.plt?). Having assigned `SOURCE`, the `TARGETS` variable is then set, now `all:` has files specified to build. and the matching rule is now run.

Comment: yes, your chain of reasoning is right.

Comment: Using .plt instead of *.plt doesn't work because `wildcard` function takes a shell glob expression. From [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcards): The wildcard characters in make are `*`, `?` and `[...]`, the same as in the Bourne shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`all : %.tex` won't work because there is no percent in the target name, in other words, it is not a patter rule.

Use [`wildcard` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function) to get the list of all `.plt` files and add an `all` dependence on these files with the extension replaced by `.tex`:

```
PLT_FILES := $(wildcard *.plt)
TARGETS   := $(PLT_FILES:%.plt=%.tex)

all: $(TARGET)
%.tex: %.plt
    gnuplot < $<
```